# How to draw a turnstile with an arrow?

Tags: symbols, turnstile

I'd like to draw a turnstile with an arrow. It looks like what is shown in the picture. Is there any command for it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Is this different from `\mapsto`?

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a symbol?”](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Maybe the vertical line on the left is longer.

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin I'll try it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build one from a regular `\vdash` turnstile.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\turnstile}{%
    \mathrel{%
        \vdash\hspace*{-5pt}%
        \raisebox{2.65pt}{\scalebox{.33}{\(\blacktriangleright\)}}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\( \Gamma \turnstile t : T \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I want.